# LESS nesting with selectors

Tags: css, less

I have the following code

```
.signin-input{
    input{
        width: 100%;
        height: 2.5rem;
        color: black;

        :placeholder-shown{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    }
```

It results in the following CSS

```
.signin-input input :not(:placeholder-shown) {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

And that fires and error of a bad selector. how to make less treat it correctly like

```
.signin-input input:not(:placeholder-shown) {
      opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to use `&`

```
.signin-input {
   input {
      width: 100%;
      height: 2.5rem;
      color: black;
      &:placeholder-shown {
          opacity: 1;
      }
   }
}
```

Will result to

```css
.signin-input input:placeholder-shown {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

> The & operator represents the parent selectors of a nested rule and is most commonly used when applying a modifying class or pseudo-class to an existing selector. *source: [lesscss.org](http://lesscss.org/features/)*